# Get external coordinates of a polygon from a numpy boolean grid

Tags: python, numpy, shapely

I am trying to get the external coordinates of a polygon from a numpy boolean grid. For example, from a (16, 16) ndarray such as the following one

```
[
    [False False False False False False  True  True  True  True False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False  True  True  True  True  True  True False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False  True  True False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False  False True False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False],
    [False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False False]
]
```

If we plot that `ndarray` it will be like the following:

[image: Boolean grid as image]

I would like to get the following coordinates, in order, such that we could draw the external ring of such polygon, e.g., `[(5 1), (6 0), (7 0), (8 0), (9 0), (10 1), (11 2), (11 3), (10 2), (9 1), (8 1), (7 1), (6 1)]`. What I have so far is the following:

```
# Consider that the boolean ndarray above is called 'prediction'

import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get the coordinates that match the boolean polygon
(y, x) = np.where(prediction == True)

# Iterate on each of the coordinates, however my problem is that it is not aware of the contour order as it should be :/
coordinates = [Point(x_coordinate, y_coordinate) for x_coordinate, y_coordinate in itertools.izip(x, y)]
# Build the polygon out of the points
polygon = Polygon([[coordinate.x, coordinate.y] for coordinate in coordinates])

exterior_x, exterior_y = polygon.exterior.xy

# Plotting

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax.plot(exterior_x, exterior_y, color='#6699cc')
ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(prediction)
plt.show()
```

The problem is that I am building the polygon not considering the order so that the result of `polygon.exterior.xy` will create the external ring. My approach will create the wrong contour of the polygon such as:

[image]

However, I am unable to come up with a general approach for this problem. I welcome any suggestion on how to tackle this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can move the question to [GIS stack exchange site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/). There you will probably get more help on this.

Anyway, a quick search shows [this anwer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187877/how-to-polygonize-raster-to-shapely-polygons), where it is suggested to use `rasterio` library, which I understand is what you need.

Adapted to your case, it can be something as:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio.features

# Convert your array to 0-1 integers
myarray = [[1 if t else 0 for t in row] for row in myarray]
# Build a numpy array
myarray = np.array(myarray)
# Convert the type (don't even know why this was needed in my computer, but raised exception if not converted.
myarray = myarray.astype(np.int32)

# Let the library do the magic. You should take a look at the rasterio.features.shapes output
mypols = [p[0]['coordinates'] 
                   for p in  rasterio.features.shapes(myarray)]
```

`mypols` is now an array of coordinates that you can easily convert to `shapely` Polygons.

Beware of properly testing stranger cases. I tried to build a multipolygon, and the library returned each connected component as a polygon. Fortunately, it returns for each polygon the associated value, so you can post process as you like.
Polygons with interior rings seem to be handled OK, though.
 I don't know what is the behavior you would expect in those cases.

Comment: This answer is linked only and therefore subject to deletion.See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/216712). Please remedy this problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll complete it.

Comment: It worked really well, thanks. I have tried also an alpha shape (concave hull) around the `coordinates` but it was too on larger images slow compared with your proposed solution.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. In this type of complex problems, it is always worthy to do a full search on the web. Remeber that stack exchange have several other sites more specific for other needs, although you will always have a quicker answer here in SO.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use ConvexHull, it tries to find the smallest enveloppe which contains all your points, that would be the polygon contour : [ConvexHull with Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html)

Comment: A concave hull would replicate the boundary.  A convex hull will not in this particular case, since it isn't a convex polygon.